# Modal does not opens when clicking a button

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

```
I am trying to call a modal from another component when I click a button.
```

This is the code for modal component :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  closeResult: string;
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,private fb:FormBuilder) {}
  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }
  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return  `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I am calling this from another template using

Here is modal template:

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Modal Body</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch modal</button>
```

And, this is how I am calling modal component in another component :

```
<h1>Hello Folks !!!</h1>
      <app-modal></app-modal>
```

Can anyone tell whats wrong? Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You mispelled Hermione

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
 Arrays.stream(array).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Comment: `forEachOrdere(...)` is an abstract method. There is no guarantee it is implemented with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

The only other example that springs to mind is available in Java 8+ and uses lambdas. Like,

```
Arrays.stream(array).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

or (from the comments)

```
Arrays.asList(array).forEach(System.out::println);
```

or (another example)

```
Stream.of(array).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

or you could always use a `while` loop (assuming you're interested in loops in general, and not `for` loops in particular)

```
int i = 0;
while (i < array.length) {
    System.out.println(array[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: `forEach(...)` and `forEachOrdered(...)` are abstract methods. There is no guarantee they are implemented with a `for` loop. And your second example is not a `for` loop. =)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have shown some good suggestions leveraging *internal iteration* of the stream library i.e. you specify the "what" and the stream library handles the "how".

Considering your current code snippet; using `forEach` or `forEachOrdered` should do the job. However, if you want access to the index as you're performing some data processing then `forEach` or `forEachOrdered` will not suffice.

This may happen when you want to perform some more complex logic and need the index as well as the element, or it may be as simple as printing the names of people in the array as well as showing their position in the array.

In this case, you can utilise `IntStrean.range`.

```
IntStream.range(0, array.length)
         .forEach(i -> System.out.println(array[i]));
```